# Inverse limit: show the surjectivity of $\mu_{ij}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A_i$ rings and $$P=\left\{(a_i)\in \prod_i A_i\mid\forall i\leq j, \mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i\right\}$$
where $\mu_{ji}:A_j\to A_i$ are rings homomorphism. We defined $\mu_i: P\to A_i$ by the projection on the $i$-th component. We want to prove that if $\mu_{ji}$ are surjective (for all $i$ and $j$), then so is every $\mu_i$. There is a proof [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/basic-properties-of-inverse-limits/) (part 2.). I don't understand why they introduce $t$ in the second part of the proof.

I mean, when they write :

*For base case, let $j=i=0$. Then $\mu_{j,i}(a_j)=a_i$. Suppose now for some $t\geq 0$ whenever $i\leq j\leq t$, $\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i$. Now consider...*

Why do they introduce this $t$? It doesn't look really necessary, no? Any explanation would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Notice that the proof that you are asking about is done only for the case $I = \Bbb N$. Why do you waste your time with this very restrictive case instead of looking for a proof that works for arbitary $I$?

Comment: @AlexM.: Because my exercise is in this very restrictive" case. But if it's obvious for you, you should be able to answer, no ?

Comment: Let me retract that: I don't know whether the statement is true for arbitrary index sets.

Comment: The possibilities for the index set $I$ are severely limited, though I do not believe having it be linearly ordered is a necessary condition (which the author implies). The author asks about whether transfinite induction, involving ordinals larger than $\omega$, would be manageable. I think not: why should it be possible to construct $a_{\omega}$ given $a_i$ for $i<\omega$ such that $\mu_{\omega,i}(a_{\omega})=a_i$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I have changed my answer, showing that $t$ is actually unnecessary.

The use of the variable $t$ is indeed superfluous, and the author did not make it transparent why this variable appears at all. Let us step through the proof of part 2, rewriting the proof by induction at the end so as to not use $t$.

We are given rings 
$$A_0,A_1,A_2,\dots,$$
and ring homomorphisms that go from higher indices to lower indices:
$$\mu_{ji}\colon A_j\to A_i\quad\text{where $i\le j$}.$$
The ring homomorphisms are assumed to satisfy two conditions: First, $\mu_{ii}$ is the identity homomorphism from $A_i$ into $A_i$ for all $i$. Second, the following composition rule holds:
$$\mu_{ji}\circ\mu_{kj}=\mu_{ki}\quad\text{for all $i\le j\le k$}.$$

The set you call $P$ is the set of all tuples $(a_i)$ in the product $\prod_{i\ge 0}A_i$ that are in a sense closed under the homomorphisms $\mu_{ji}$. More precisely,
$$\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i\quad\text{for all $i\le j$}.$$

Now, the claim is that when the homomorphisms $\mu_{ji}$ are all surjective, then for any $k\in\mathbb N$ and any $a\in A_k$, there exists $(a_i)\in P$ such that $a_k=a$. In other words, the $k$th coordinate projection of $P$ is surjective.

Let $k\in\mathbb N$ and $a\in A_k$. The author constructs a tuple
$$(a_i)\in\prod_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$$
such that $a_k=a$, as follows. If $i\le k$, we can simply use our homomorphism $\mu_{ki}$, defining
$$a_i=\mu_{ki}(a).$$
If $i>k$ and $a_{i'}$ has been defined for all $i'<i$, then we use the surjective property of $\mu_{i,i-1}$ and the given $a_{i-1}$. Indeed, since $\mu_{i,i-1}$ is surjective and $a_{i-1}\in A_{i-1}$, there exists some $x\in A_i$ such that
$$\mu_{i,i-1}(x)=a_{i-1}.$$
Thus, we define $a_i=x$. Recursively, $a_i$ is defined for all $i\in\mathbb N$.

Now, we need to show that $(a_i)$ belongs to $P$. It is evident from the construction that $a_i\in A_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$. We need to prove $\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i$ for all natural numbers $i\le j$. We will prove that by induction on $j$.

The basis step: $j=0$. Let $i\le j$, so that $i=0$ as well. Then, $\mu_{ji}=\mu_{00}$ is the identity on $A_0$, so $\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_j=a_0$ and $a_i=a_0$, implying $\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i$ in this case.

The induction step: assume that $j$ is a natural number such that $\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i$ for all $i\le j$. Let $i\le j+1$. Either $i=j+1$ or $i\le j$. In the first case, $\mu_{j+1,i}(a_{j+1})=a_i$ since $\mu_{j+1,i}$ is the identity and $a_i=a_{j+1}$. We will now assume $i\le j$. We will first show that
$$\mu_{j+1,j}(a_{j+1})=a_j$$
using a proof by cases.

If $j+1\le k$, then
$$a_{j+1}=\mu_{k,j+1}(a)\quad\text{and}\quad a_j=\mu_{kj}(a)$$
so 
$$\mu_{j+1,j}(a_{j+1})=(\mu_{j+1,j}\circ\mu_{k,j+1})(a)=\mu_{kj}(a)=a_j$$

If $j>k$, then as we constructed $(a_i)$ above,
$$\mu_{j+1,j}(a_{j+1})=a_j.$$

Therefore, $\mu_{j+1,j}(a_{j+1})=a_j$. Furthermore, by the induction hypothesis, and the assumption $i\le j$,
$$\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i.$$
Then,
$$\mu_{j+1,i}(a_{j+1})=(\mu_{ji}\circ\mu_{j+1,j})(a_{j+1})=\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i.$$

By our proof by induction we have shown that $\mu_{ji}(a_j)=a_i$ for all $i\le j$. Therefore, $(a_i)\in P$.

This revision of the author's proof illustrates that there is no need to make use of an additional variable $t$ for the induction.

Comment: I think it's good. I will stud it more in detail tomorrow and of course give you the bounty if it's good. Thanks for the effort of all your explanations.